# Формирование обучающей выборки путем преобразований нескольких изображений

Tags: нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение

Здравствуйте. Возникла следующая закономерная проблема при обучении нейронной сети: На входе имеется 5 изображений одного и того же объекта с разных ракурсов (Для примера взял коробку, каждая грань которой имеет рисунки, надписи, т.е. уникальность градиентов и пр.), произвел обучение нейросети, которая производит бинарную классификацию (есть ли на изображении объект или нет), с этим набором данных в обучающей выборке, закономерен итог: не хватило данных для нормального процента точных распознаваний. Возник вопрос: если внести в выборку изображения построенные на базе исходных пяти, но преобразованные по различным признакам (сдвиг, масштаб, контрастность, яркость, пр.), то смогу ли я добиться лучших показателей обученности? Если да, то есть ли какая-нибудь библиотека, которая способна в этом помочь?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте воспользоваться [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/image#Image_Adjustments):

```
tf.image.adjust_brightness
tf.image.random_brightness
tf.image.adjust_contrast
tf.image.random_contrast
tf.image.adjust_hue
tf.image.random_hue
tf.image.adjust_gamma
tf.image.adjust_saturation
tf.image.random_saturation
tf.image.per_image_standardization
```